# Binding constructor object does not create a correct object

Tags: javascript

I tried to bind a constructor object:

```js
"use strict";
    
let Person = function(name){
  this.name = name;
}

let age = {
  age: 128
}

let AgedPerson = Person.bind(age)
console.log(new AgedPerson("John"))
```

Since `bind` essentially sets up a context with `this` pointing out to some object and then `new` initializes `this` and returns it I expected that the following would be printed:

```
{
  age: 128,
  name: "John"
}
```

but instead got:

```
{
  name: "John"
}
```

Why is the `age` field lost after creating the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) before a function, the function is called with a `this` value set to a new empty object, regardless of whether you used `.bind()` on the function beforehand (ie: the `this` value you had set is ignored).

Since your function doesn't return anything and you're using the `new` keyword, the default behavior is for the function to then return the `this` value once it's finished executing. In your case, `AgedPerson` is called, with a `this` set to an empty object `{}` (due to the `new` keyword). `this` is then updated within the function to add the `name` property to it, which is then implicitly returned, giving you `{name: "John"}`.

[`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) comes into play when your function invoked in other ways (eg: with `()`, as well as `.call()` or `.apply()`), but not when using `new`, for example:

```js
"use strict";

const person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const age = { age: 128 };

const agedPerson = person.bind(age)
agedPerson("John"); // modifies the age object by reference
console.log(age); // { age: 128, name: "John" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the Nick Parsons' answer you just call a constructor on an object, so the object doesn't became a true instance of `Person`. You can fix it by setting its prototype.

Also you can use `Function::call()` to combine the binding and the calling into one operation.

```js
"use strict";

const Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const age = { age: 128 };

Person.call(age, 'John');
Object.setPrototypeOf(age, Person.prototype);

console.log('age is Person:', age instanceof Person);
console.log(age); // { age: 128, name: "John" }
```